# Kendo Dropdown databindg with javascript

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I've a javascript method which is returning below output.

```
  Ex:  http://localhost/jsfunctions/reademps

        {"Success":true,"Model":["Raju","Ram","Sri"]}
```

can someone tell me how to bind this to my kendodropdown?

```
 $("#dvEmps").kendoDropDownList({
             dataSource: ???
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should just be

```
$("#dvEmps").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: reademps().Model        
});
```

Running on page load:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dvEmps").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: reademps().Model        
    });
});
```

Comment: You may need to run this after the page has loaded- your javascript function may not have been loaded yet. $(function () { YOURCODE; });

Comment: How can I do this? any specific implementation is there? can you give me a piece of code?

Comment: I updated the code above. I'm not sure this is your problem, but this shows what I'm talking about. This is one of several syntaxes for attaching code that will execute when the page has loaded, which means that all javascript includes have been loaded as well. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/